# mode aes-gcm - can i use data block 64bit

Tags: c, encryption, 64-bit, ansi-c, aes-gcm

Does anyone have an idea how to change source code from https://github.com/mko-x/SharedAES-GCM
in the way, that supports 64 bit blocks? The implementation of this algorithm is for 128bit data block and have 96bit Initialization Vector (IV) + 32bit Counter.

I need GCM mode for support of an algorithm with 64bit data block, particular for algorithm DESXL which have 64bit data block, key for this operation can be 128bit.

Is it feasible in a relatively simple way?
I am looking for an implementation written in ANSI C.

Comment: I hope you know GCM stands for Galois Counter Mode, not Google Cloud Messaging. Why do you need GCM on top of DES? It's not like it will be compatible with anything. Also note that DES isn't secure nowadays. And AES block size is fixed 128 bits, also rijndael has a minimum block size of 128.

Comment: hi, 
for first question, 
yes i was obviously thinking about Galois Counter Mode, (I dont know why stackoverflow.com changed my gcm for Google Cloud Messaging :)

yes, I know about des - its not safe, but I need this for my research project - it is simply one of the tasks to be done

so, is it possible use alghoritm desxl with 64bits data_block on mode GCM ?

Comment: GCM uses a specific polynomial that is compatible with 128 bit block ciphers. It is *not* easy to do the same for a 64 bit block size; you would need a different one.